# Adding Status Column to Customer Information -> Orders in Magento

Tags: magento

I've been attempting to add a "Status" column in the Orders grid that's shown when you view the Customer Information -> Orders tab.

I've been able to add the column, and the filter populates with the correct status values, but it breaks the default sorting and you can't filter by any item or sort.

I know there's probably a much better way of adding the column, but all the examples I found related to the main Orders table and I couldn't figure out how to modify it for this use case.

Here's my extension code - in /Pnp/Customer/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Orders.php

```
<?php

class Pnp_Customer_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Orders extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Orders
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('customer_orders_grid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
  }

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('increment_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('customer_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('created_at')
        ->addFieldToSelect('grand_total')
        ->addFieldToSelect('order_currency_code')
        ->addFieldToSelect('store_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('billing_name')
        ->addFieldToSelect('shipping_name')
        ->addFieldToSelect('status')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId())
        ->setIsCustomerMode(true);

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return $this;
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();

        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses()
        ));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

---

Many thanks to the answers so far.

I've nearly got there with a combination of Harit and Emipro Technologies answers, here's what I have so far:

etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pnp_Customer>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </Pnp_Customer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <pnp_statusgrid>
                <class>Pnp_Customer_Model</class>
            </Pnp_statusgrid>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                <observers>
                    <statusgrid_column_append>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Pnp_Customer_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>appendCustomColumn</method>
                    </statusgrid_column_append>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Pnp_Customer_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
/**
 * Adds column to admin customers grid
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return Pnp_Customer_Model_Observer
 */
public function appendCustomColumn(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getBlock();
    if (!isset($block)) {
        return $this;
    }

    if ($block->getType() == 'adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_orders') {
        /* @var $block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid */
        $block->addColumn('status', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Status'),
            'type'      => 'options',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
            'width'     => '70px',
            'index'     => 'status',
            'renderer'  => 'Pnp_Customer_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Renderer_Status',
    }
}
}
```

Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Orders.php

```
<?php

class Pnp_Customer_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Orders extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Orders
{

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('increment_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('customer_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('created_at')
        ->addFieldToSelect('grand_total')
        ->addFieldToSelect('order_currency_code')
        ->addFieldToSelect('store_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('billing_name')
        ->addFieldToSelect('shipping_name')
        ->addFieldToSelect('status')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId())
        ->setIsCustomerMode(true);

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return $this;
}


}
```

Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Renderer/status.php

```
<?php

class Pnp_Customer_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Renderer_Status extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {


public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
if (!$value = $this->getColumn()->getIndex()){
    return $this;
} 

$value =  $row->getData('increment_id');
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($value);
return '<span >'.$order['status']'</span>';
}

}

?>
```

Everything is working except the column shows the status name as underscored, i.e. payment_pending.  I looked at the object being returned and can't see the label version.  As a final thing to get the above finished, would anyone be able to point me in the right direction to print the human readable version of the attribute?

---

Final Edit:

I managed to figure it out - I changed:

```
return '<span >'.$order['status']'</span>';
```

to

```
return '<span >'.$order->getStatusLabel().'</span>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definately work add renderer

change your column by

```
$this->addColumn('status', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Status'),
    'index'     => 'status',
    'type' => 'options',
    'options' => $this->_getorderstatus(),
    'renderer'  => 'Pnp_Customer_Block_Customer_Edit_Renderer_Status',
));
```

Add new function in same file

```
protected function _getorderstatus(){
    $ordstatus = (array) Mage::getModel('sales/order_status')->getResourceCollection()->getData();
    $orderstatus=array();

    foreach($ordstatus as $item){
        $orderstatus[$item['status']]=$item['label'];
    }
return $orderstatus;
}
```

**status.php** put function like

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
if (!$value = $this->getColumn()->getIndex()){
    return $this;
} 
$value =  $row->getData('increment_id');
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($value);
return '<span >'.$order['status'].'</span>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I tried this, but I'm not sure I put the status.php in the right place - where should this go?  Thank you.

Comment: Pnp_Customer_Block_Customer_Edit_Renderer_Status  shows path of file you need to place status.php file  app/code/[local or community]/Pnp/Customer/Block/Customer/Edit/Renderer/Status.php

Comment: Thank you - I've updated my answer to reflect where I am currently using both answers, do you have any ideas on how I can get the final part working?

Answer (score 1):

An easier and reliable way to achieve this is through observer.

1. Create a Module
2. Inside **app/code/local/My/Module/etc/config.xml**

> ```
> <global>
>     <models>
>         <my_customgrid>
>             <class>My_Module_Model</class>
>         </my_customgrid>
>     </models>
> </global>
> <adminhtml>
>     <events>
>         <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
>             <observers>
>                 <customgrid_column_append>
>                     <type>model</type>
>                     <class>My_Module_Model_Observer</class>
>                     <method>appendCustomColumn</method>
>                 </customgrid_column_append>
>             </observers>
>         </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
>     </events>
> </adminhtml>
> ```

What it does is, it allows you to observe the block before its layout is prepared.

3. Create a file called Observer.php for your module and write down following:

   class My_Module_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer {

   ```
   /**
    * 
    * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
    * @return \My_Module_Model_Observer
    */
   public function appendCustomColumn(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
       $block = $observer->getBlock();
       if (!isset($block)) {
           return $this;
       }

       if ($block->getType() == 'adminhtml/customer_grid') {
           /* @var $block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid */
           $block->addColumnAfter('field', array(
               'header' => 'Your Field',
               'type' => 'text',
               'index' => 'field',
                   ), 'email');
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Follow this link for more information:
http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-column-to-customers-grid-alternative-way/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.

I had tried working through this tutorial, and it does look like this would be the best way to do what I need to, but I'm struggling getting it to work with the grid I need.

I've tried to target it by updating the block as follows: $block->getType() == 'adminhtml/edit_tab_orders

Do you know if that's right for the grid I want to update, or should I change anything else?  No status column appears with this code.

Thank you.

Comment: Actually, it does seem to work with customer_edit_tab_orders so I think I'm a step closer!  Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Hopefully you achieve what you need.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm nearly there - I just have one last point that's not working.  Do you know what I can do to fix this?